# sitecore fields data type for xml data

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

I will need to save a serialized data in a field. Can anybody please help me figure out how can i do it in sitecore.

In a sql server I can define `xml` field-type which is sufficient for this. But similarly I can't find anything in sitecore. Though there are two types called `html` & `memo` which are deprecated. Also want to know can I use any of these.

We are using sitecore 7.2 BTW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply store it in a multi-line text field. If you wanted to get real fancy then you could create a custom field type. I've previously even used an IFrame field type for this kind of data, since the text is blanked out to the end user (but still viewable using Raw Values) and since the underlying data is just text it worked fine.

In any case, if your field is populated automatically from an external source then you probably don't want that data editable from the content editor. Lock the field down using the security editor and using correct roles & permissions so that normal editors do not have Field Write permissions (set on the template itself, not the created items)

Comment: Thanks. But I will save the serialized data from codebase. If I lock the field from security editor will I be able to do that?

Comment: Yes you will, it will only lock the field in the Content Editor and only for particular roles. In your code you would normally use SecurityDiabler or UserSwitcher to write to the item anyway, which would bypass the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore, all fields are internally kept as strings by design (except media blobs). I think the best field type to store serialized XML would be **multi-line text**.

Of course, you should care about all serialization and deserialization the data into that field